# OpenGL: glDrawArrays() throws exception (nvoglv32.dll) Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, opengl, access-violation, gldrawarrays

So I've made a basic OpenGL application and everything was fine until I implemented a Geometry shader.

The error im getting is 
**Exception thrown at 0x6A67F00A (nvoglv32.dll) in Demo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.**

Now, I dont know if the shader is whats causing the issue but it worked fine until I implemented it.

Ive done some googling and there seems to be a bunch of different reasons for it, many of them having to do with the VAO's, which have remained unchanged.

The error occurs at `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);`

Here is my C++ code:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// BTH - Stefan Petersson 2014.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <windows.h>

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>

#include <gl/glew.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include "glm/glm/glm.hpp"
#include "glm/glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"
#include "glm/glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp"

#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")

using namespace std;

HWND InitWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
HGLRC CreateOpenGLContext(HWND wndHandle);

GLuint gVertexBuffer = 0;
GLuint gVertexAttribute = 0;
GLuint gShaderProgram = 0;

//is bad but ok
glm::mat4 World = glm::mat4(1.0f);
glm::mat4 View;
glm::mat4 Projection;
//

#define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ((char *)nullptr + (i))


void CreateMatrices() {


    glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(0, 0, 3), // Camera is at (4,3,3), in World Space
        glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), // and looks at the origin
        glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
    );

    // Projection matrix : 45° Field of View, 4:3 ratio, display range : 0.1 unit <-> 100 units
    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)640 / (float)480, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    World = glm::rotate(World, 0.01f, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));



    glm::mat4 mvp = Projection * View * World;

    GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(gShaderProgram, "MVP");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0]);
}


void CreateTriangleData()
{
    // this is how we will structure the input data for the vertex shader
    // every six floats, is one vertex.
    struct TriangleVertex
    {
        float x, y, z;
        float r, g, b;
    };
    // create the actual data in plane Z = 0
    TriangleVertex triangleVertices[6] =
    {
        // pos and color for each vertex
        //first triangle
        { -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },
        {  0.5f, 0.5f, -0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },
        {  0.5f, -0.5f, -0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
        //second triangle
        { 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
        { -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },
        { -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }
    };

    // Vertex Array Object (VAO) 
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &gVertexAttribute);
    // bind == enable
    glBindVertexArray(gVertexAttribute);
    // this activates the first and second attributes of this VAO
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    // create a vertex buffer object (VBO) id
    glGenBuffers(1, &gVertexBuffer);
    // Bind the buffer ID as an ARRAY_BUFFER
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gVertexBuffer);
    // This "could" imply copying to the GPU, depending on what the driver wants to do...
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangleVertices), triangleVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // query where which slot corresponds to the input vertex_position in the Vertex Shader 
    GLuint vertexPos = glGetAttribLocation(gShaderProgram, "vertex_position");
    // specify that: the vertex attribute "vertexPos", of 3 elements of type FLOAT, not normalized, with STRIDE != 0,
    //               starts at offset 0 of the gVertexBuffer (it is implicitly bound!)
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexPos, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TriangleVertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    // query where which slot corresponds to the input vertex_color in the Vertex Shader 
    GLuint vertexColor = glGetAttribLocation(gShaderProgram, "vertex_color");
    // specify that: the vertex attribute "vertex_color", of 3 elements of type FLOAT, not normalized, with STRIDE != 0,
    //               starts at offset (12 bytes) of the gVertexBuffer 
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexColor, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TriangleVertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(float) * 3));

}

void SetViewport()
{
    glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
}

void CreateShaders()
{

    //create vertex shader
    GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    // open glsl file and put it in a string
    ifstream shaderFile("VertexShader.glsl");
    std::string shaderText((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(shaderFile)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    shaderFile.close();
    // make a double pointer (only valid here)
    const char* shaderTextPtr = shaderText.c_str();
    // ask GL to load this
    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &shaderTextPtr, nullptr);
    // ask GL to compile it
    glCompileShader(vs);

    //create fragment shader | same process.
    GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    shaderFile.open("Fragment.glsl");
    shaderText.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(shaderFile)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    shaderFile.close();
    shaderTextPtr = shaderText.c_str();
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &shaderTextPtr, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fs);

    ///create geometry shader | same process.
    GLuint gs = glCreateShader(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER);
    shaderFile.open("Geometry.glsl");
    shaderText.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(shaderFile)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    shaderFile.close();
    shaderTextPtr = shaderText.c_str();
    glShaderSource(gs, 1, &shaderTextPtr, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(gs);

    //link shader program (connect vs and ps)
    gShaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(gShaderProgram, fs);
    glAttachShader(gShaderProgram, vs);
    glAttachShader(gShaderProgram, gs);
    glLinkProgram(gShaderProgram);
    glUseProgram(gShaderProgram);


}

void Render()
{
    CreateMatrices();
    // set the color TO BE used
    glClearColor(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    // use the color to clear the color buffer
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

}

int WINAPI wWinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    HWND wndHandle = InitWindow(hInstance); //1. Skapa fönster

    if (wndHandle)
    {
        HDC hDC = GetDC(wndHandle);
        HGLRC hRC = CreateOpenGLContext(wndHandle); //2. Skapa och koppla OpenGL context

        glewInit(); //3. Initiera The OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library (GLEW)

        CreateShaders();

        SetViewport(); //4. Sätt viewport

        CreateTriangleData(); //6. Definiera triangelvertiser, 7. Skapa vertex buffer object (VBO), 8.Skapa vertex array object (VAO)



        ShowWindow(wndHandle, nCmdShow);

        while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
        {
            if (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
            else
            {
                Render(); //9. Rendera

                SwapBuffers(hDC); //10. Växla front- och back-buffer

            }
        }

        wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
        ReleaseDC(wndHandle, hDC);
        wglDeleteContext(hRC);
        DestroyWindow(wndHandle);
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

HWND InitWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex = { 0 };
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX); 
    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"BTH_GL_DEMO";
    if( !RegisterClassEx(&wcex) )
        return false;

    RECT rc = { 0, 0, 640, 480 };
    AdjustWindowRect( &rc, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE );

    HWND handle = CreateWindow(
        L"BTH_GL_DEMO",
        L"BTH OpenGL Demo",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        rc.right - rc.left,
        rc.bottom - rc.top,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        hInstance,
        nullptr);

    return handle;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch (message) 
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;      
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

HGLRC CreateOpenGLContext(HWND wndHandle)
{
    //get handle to a device context (DC) for the client area
    //of a specified window or for the entire screen
    HDC hDC = GetDC(wndHandle);

    //details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318286(v=vs.85).aspx
    static  PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pixelFormatDesc =
    {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),    // size of this pfd  
        1,                                // version number  
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |              // support window  
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |              // support OpenGL  
        PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER |                // double buffered
        PFD_DEPTH_DONTCARE,               // disable depth buffer <-- added by Stefan
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                    // RGBA type  
        32,                               // 32-bit color depth  
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                 // color bits ignored  
        0,                                // no alpha buffer  
        0,                                // shift bit ignored  
        0,                                // no accumulation buffer  
        0, 0, 0, 0,                       // accum bits ignored  
        0,                                // 0-bits for depth buffer <-- modified by Stefan      
        0,                                // no stencil buffer  
        0,                                // no auxiliary buffer  
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,                   // main layer  
        0,                                // reserved  
        0, 0, 0                           // layer masks ignored  
    };

    //attempt to match an appropriate pixel format supported by a
    //device context to a given pixel format specification.
    int pixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pixelFormatDesc);

    //set the pixel format of the specified device context
    //to the format specified by the iPixelFormat index.
    SetPixelFormat(hDC, pixelFormat, &pixelFormatDesc);

    //create a new OpenGL rendering context, which is suitable for drawing
    //on the device referenced by hdc. The rendering context has the same
    //pixel format as the device context.
    HGLRC hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);

    //makes a specified OpenGL rendering context the calling thread's current
    //rendering context. All subsequent OpenGL calls made by the thread are
    //drawn on the device identified by hdc. 
    wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);

    return hRC;
}
```

Here are my shaders:

> Vertex shader (pass-through)

```
#version 400
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertex_color;

out vec3 color;

void main() {
    color = vertex_color;
    gl_Position = vec4(vertex_position, 1.0);
}
```

> Geometry Shader (redundant, but needed for assignment)

```
#version 400
layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices=3) out;

uniform mat4 MVP;

in vec3 color[];
out vec3 pass_color[];
void main()
{   
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    gl_Position = MVP * gl_in[i].gl_Position;
    pass_color[i] = color[i];
    EmitVertex();
  }
  EndPrimitive();
}
```

> Fragment Shader

```
#version 400
in vec3 pass_color;
out vec4 fragment_color;

void main () {
    fragment_color = vec4 (pass_color, 1.0);
}
```

Its a fair amount of code.. I would ask my teacher about it but he is not available during the weekends.

If you need any other information let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why aren't you checking the shader compilation and link statuses?

Comment: Most of this code was supplied to me by my teacher, including the CreateShaders()-function..

Answer (score 0):

Usually that error happens when you [failed to initialize function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883985/gldrawarrays-access-violation?rq=1) to GL functions.Based on your code I can see your Windows setup for GL context looks incomplete to me.You don't initialize intermediate ["dummy" context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.1_The_First_Triangle_(C%2B%2B/Win)).The web has plenty of examples of correct GL context  setup using Windows API.And you must improve your error handling.For example,check for errors when calling:

```
glewInit()
```

Based on how you setup your OpenGL context,you probably run with the default GL version (1.1 ,if I remember correctly).But you want to use GS which requires OpenGL 4.0,and you don't request it when creating the context.See the link I provided that show how to request a specific GL version.As I mentioned above,your setup is incomplete for modern OpenGL context.

Comment: Well the thing is most of this is coded by my teacher, I have close to no idea whats going on in main() at all (except the loop)..
But like I said, it all worked fine earlier, I didnt change much, just added the geometry shader..

Comment: The geometry shader requires modern OpenGL setup.In your case,based on how you create the context,you don't have OpenGL version active,that supports GS (4.0)

Comment: Hm alright that sounds logical, however if I remove the GS completely it still gives me an access violation.